# MySQL Query BETWEEN Null and something big

Tags: mysql

first post here for me.

Im pretty new to MySQL but i try to do my best. I've searched the web and found out that query's including Null can be quite a hassle.

I'll try to explain my problem.
I have a table containing soil analysis, around 400k rows, with about 30 columns. Some of the fields doesn't have values but instead have Null.
I let the user specify a range between minimum and maximum value for 7 different columns. 
So that i 14 different variables in PHP.

If the users doesn't specify i set the minimum variable to 0 and the maximum to 100000. Now comes the issue, since some of the values in the table include Null, the BETWEEN comparison doesn't really work when i try to compare with Null.

Then the whole row will not be included in the result, there could be other values on that row that i want to include.
I've included my query if it is to any help.
Would really like some help. I feel that the issue is solvable, but I've tried googling now for a while and can't find other people with the same problem.

/Simon

```
$sql = "SELECT `kundnr`, `Year`, `Provnr`, `pH`, `P_AL`, `P_HCl`, `K_AL`, `K_HCl`, `Mg_AL`,
        `Cu_HCl`, `K_Mg_kvot`, `Bor`, `Ca_AL`, `Total_lerhalt`, `Sand_grovmo`, `Mullhalt`

        FROM `analyser`

        WHERE (`pH` > 0)

        AND (`pH` BETWEEN $minph AND $maxph)
        AND (`P_AL` BETWEEN $minpal AND $maxpal)
        AND (`K_AL` BETWEEN $minkal AND $maxkal)
        AND (`Mg_AL` BETWEEN $minmg AND $maxmg)
        AND (`Total_lerhalt` BETWEEN $minler AND $maxler)
        AND (`Mullhalt` BETWEEN $minmull AND $maxmull)
        AND (`Sand_grovmo` BETWEEN $minsgrovmo AND $maxsgrovmo)

        LIMIT 0,$limitrows";
```

Comment: COALESCE() is your friend.

Comment: I looked into that one as well, but couldn't wrap my head around it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the rows with null values included, replace the `null`s with the min (or max) values:

e.g.:
    `AND (IFNULL(`K_AL`, $minkal) BETWEEN $minkal AND $maxkal)`

Comment: This seem to have solved the problem. But i chose to set it like this:
No big difference.


`(IFNULL(K_AL, 0) BETWEEN $minkal AND $maxkal)`

Comment: That's fine if your `$minkal = 0`